How to prevent my spec suite to be super-slow?
On one of my project, the CI is super-slow, even so slow that we can't run some specs on all machines or it takes hours. Yes, hours.
It shouldn't take that long, that's for sure, because those specs are mostly very trivial and there aren't millions of them.
We've tried to pin down the issue, and we've a few leads but couldn't find any precise reason why it's so slow.
-> Not all the spec suite is impacted, only those that imply the front
-> When exploring it with TestProf, it shows that most of the execution time was just sleeping (see result on a sample of 50 tests)
==================================
  Mode: wall(1000)
  Samples: 479622 (1.44% miss rate)
  GC: 2120 (0.44%)
==================================
     TOTAL    (pct)     SAMPLES    (pct)     FRAME
    420932  (87.8%)      420932  (87.8%)     Kernel#sleep
     37954   (7.9%)       37954   (7.9%)     Thread::Mutex#sleep
      5852   (1.2%)        5852   (1.2%)     PG::Connection#exec
      2436   (0.5%)        2433   (0.5%)     PG::Connection#exec_params
      1406   (0.3%)        1406   (0.3%)     (marking)

Obviously, we've explored our suite to remove all potential mentions of sleep but that's not it.
If it's any help, the project is now using rails 7, with Webpacker 5

Try running it on just chunks of the test suite. My guess is that most of the use of sleep is happening in feature/system specs to wait for the DOM.

I've tried running it on just one file of the suite, which contains absolutely no sleep call, and still sleeps a lot
It's indeed feature/system specs that are impacted.

How many feature specs are there? What tooling have you used to implement them (e.g. Capybara)?

Not that many, like several hundreds. It seemed to be hanged up because of AppSignal, I am still ensuring it's properly fix and I'll give more details then
